# Flutter better_player android Duplicate class found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime.jar and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.1-runtime.jar

Tags: flutter

When running Flutter build apk with version 0.0.81 the following error is thrown

1 exception was raised by workers: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.1)[BUG]

I tried to exclude the module and group in android's build.gradle and still it does not work.
My pubspec.yaml
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

So how can I use better_player: 0.0.81

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, apparently the issue is that I was using video_player (2.3.0) and better_player (0.0.81). video_player depends on [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) 2.17 while better_player depends on [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) 2.15. I downgraded video_player to 2.1.12 (in pubspec.yaml you may need to write `video_player: 2.1.12` WITHOUT `^`).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by adding

```
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.0')
```

at dependencies in /android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.0')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was resolved with:

- In `pubspec.yaml`, if you have both `better_player` and `video_player` in the project, you need to reduce the `video_player version to 2.1.12`, so that there is no conflict between the `better_player` internal `video_player` version.

This worked for me. Hope it helps more people!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and I solve it by using an old version of `pubspec.lock`  and cleaning the cache with `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache clean` and running `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Chewie package installed, it might cause an issue because it depends on a non-compatible version of video_player. Better Player works with video_player 2.1.12. I was having a hard time finding this solution since the error I was debugging was `<aynschronous suspension>` when initiating BetterPlayer, however this is the solution I just confirmed it.